# Does OCI-Lob::import function stream the data?

Tags: php, oracle, blob

I am using [`OCI-LOB::import`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oci-lob.import.php) to store a file into database.

1. What will happen if the file is large, larger than php [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting? Will `OCI-LOB::import` do streaming and send file data to database by smaller chunks, or not?
2. Are there any OCI functions, which can control the LOB-related streaming of data? Most important, for setting chunk size, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examination of `oci8_lob.c` from PHP 5.3.18 source found that

1. `OCI-LOB::import` reads file data and write into LOB descriptor using fixed sized buffer. Length of buffer is set to 8192 bytes and is hardcoded in source. That means, `OCI-LOB::import` sends data to database using 8K-sized chunks.
2. It is impossible to modify chunk size, which is used by `OCI-LOB::import`, since it is hardcoded in source.

Answer (score 1):

1) you don't have to worry about php's memory_limit when you write large data into lob

2) you can write data to lob object by chunks using `OCI-Lob::write` function

```
$chunkSize = 1024;
$f = fopen ($filename, 'r');
while ($buf = fread($f, $chunkSize))
{
    $lob->write($buf);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, voted up for it. I read implementation in php source code and that answered to my first part of question more precise.